# Does node.js `response.end` event ever send the optional `data` and `encoding` parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-handling

The documentation defines `response.end([data][, encoding][, callback])`, and states:

> If data is specified, it is equivalent to calling response.write(data,
>   encoding) followed by response.end(callback).

Am I using the `end` event correctly, or is it highly unlikely anyone would pass data into the `end` event?

```
var http = require('http');

http.get(
    process.argv[2],
    function (response) {
        response.setEncoding('utf8');
        response.on('error', console.error);
        response.on('data', console.log);

        // Check for data and exit on 'end' event
        response.on(
            'end',
            function (data, encoding) {
                if ( null != data ) {
                    console.log(data.toString(encoding));
                }
                return;
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Comment: are you able to see the data in the on end?

Comment: In my specific instance, it is `undefined`, as it would be if it were not passed. I expected this because it is optional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`response.on('end'...)` indicated that there is no more data in the response.

The `data` is sent in chunks as mentioned in the docs. It is a readable stream, `on('end')` allows you to pass in your own data, you could have simple text in there and that is what would be written like so:

The docs are essentially explaining the two ways you can do this.

Example:

```
response.write('Hello World\n');
response.end();

OR
response.end('Hello World\n');
```

Generally speaking this is fine for small amounts of data, but chunking of the data is handled in `response.on('data'...);` which is where you can put the data into lets say, an Array, and then pass that Array in to `response.on('end'...)` which is how I would recommend doing it for larger chunked data. A good exercise might be to log the data in a callback to see it come through.

Edit:

To your question in the comments:

Your code is correct, and optional, think about it this way, you send something to that function, a request, it does a response, that response if its large is broken into chunks, you can get those chunks in `on(data)`, you can send it back at the end using `on(end)`, simple as that

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for responding so quickly, but I am still confused whether or not the code I have shown above is correct or even necessary?

Comment: it is correct, and optional, think about it this way, you send something to that  function, a request, it does a response, that response if its large is broken into chunks, you can get those chunks in on(data), you can send it back at the end using on(end), simple as that

Comment: I'll give you the check if you'll move that up to your answer, ahead of your more detailed response.